# Home, Menu, Back Buttons are not clickable in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, home-button

I have noticed that in some of emulators mainnavigation buttons (Home, Back, Menu) buttons are not clickable. If the emulator's device is something which has a higher resolution this is mostly happening if I have observed it correctly. Does anyone know why is this and any solution for this?

Thanks,
Madhura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to modify the Device Definitions. To do this, find the "Device Definitions" tab in the Android Virtual Device Manager and double click on the device you're using.

Make sure the Buttons are set to Hardware.

[image]

Don't forget to update your device settings:

[image]

Source: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100251/avd-hardware-buttons-not-enabled)